# Desencadear um evento após dois clicks em botão

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena interface em `Tkinter`, mas tenho a seguinte duvida: Existe algum um evento de mouse que permita que uma ação seja executada após dois *clicks* consecutivos em um botão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe sim, o método [`bind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), você pode informar o evento, que pode ser:

- `<Button-1>`: Um *click*.
- `<Double-Button-1>`: Dois *clicks*.
- `<Triple-Button-1>`: Três *clicks*.
- Entre outros...

Veja um exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

def foo():
    print ('foo')

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button1 = Button(frame, text = 'Foo!')
button1.pack()
button1.bind('<Double-Button-1>', foo)

root.mainloop()
```

Para mais informações veja a documentação: [**Events and Bindings**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).